# Datatable styling not working

Tags: javascript, css, datatable

I have a peculiar problem. I am developing a php site that required Datatables to work with it. I noticed that Datatables styling does not work when I run it on localhost be it Firefox or Chrome. My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        } );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
                    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this gives me a rather ugly version of the datatable. Search functionalities and filtering works but is missing styles and column reordering.

However the strange thing is that a jsfiddle that I drew up containing the same data render as expected, with all styling, etc... The fiddle link is as follows: https://jsfiddle.net/gkyya29h/

I'm using XAMPP server with firefox as my default browser. Can someone help me figure this out? I may be doing some very obvious mistake but I'm failing to see it. Thank You.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

Your link tag to CSS is wrong. Maybe some browsers won't process it correctly.

Comment: OMG...Thank you, feeling stupid now for making such a silly mistake

Comment: Glad it helped. It would be great if you could mark this question answered :)

Comment: I did not have this css included at all. Worked for me.

Comment: I was just missing the link altogether lol

Answer (score 4):

There's this simple error in link:
You wrote **rel="text/css"**

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
```

Answer (score -4):

Please download the css file from //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css and include the downloaded file in your project.

Comment: and why not ? This is very bad advice.