# PHP bootstrap Pagination with custom page select dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

With Current coding, I want to show only 5 pagination field if suitable with the number or records, otherwise auto adjusted if the number of record & user select data per page is low.

For test used country list for sample database: In the picture, this is how it looks like:
[image]

For Bigger data, it doesn't look like nice in this way.
Plus I have added a drop down list for user to jump to any pages. But that doesn't work with current coding & for loop structure.

Coding Part:

```
  <div class="form-group">
             <?php
           // display the links to the pages
           // setting up the Prev & First Button
             if($page == 1){
                echo '<ul class="pagination"><li class="disabled"><a 
                href="test_cas.php?page=1">First</a></li>';
                echo '<li class="disabled"><a href="test_cas.php?
                page='.$page.'">Prev</a></li>';
               }
        else {
               echo '<ul class="pagination"><li><a href="test_cas.php?
               page=1">First</a></li>';
               echo '<li><a href="test_cas.php?page='.($page-1).'">Prev</a>
              </li>';
             }
               $before_loop_value=$page;
         for ($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++) {
             echo '<li><a href="test_cas.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . 
                '</a><li>';   
           }
          // Setting up the Next & Last Button
         if($before_loop_value == $number_of_pages){
             echo'<li class="disabled"><a href="test_cas.php?page='.($page-
              1).'">Next</a></li>';
              echo '<li class="disabled"><a href="test_cas.php?
               page='.$number_of_pages.'">Last</a></li></ul>';
           }
        else {
             echo'<li><a href="test_cas.php?page='.($page-1).'">Next</a>
             </li>';  
             echo '<li><a href="test_cas.php?
             page='.$number_of_pages.'">Last</a></li>';
             }
              // Jump to a page Drop Down Section
                  echo '<select class="form-control" id="custom_page" 
                  name="custom_page">';
                  echo "<option value='" . $page . "'>" . $page . "
                  </option>";
                  echo'</select>';
                   echo'</ul>';
                     ?> 
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">Total Record <?php echo 
                    $number_of_results?>
                 </div>
```

Bootstrap has an option for `<li class="active">` Not sure how to implement that with this structure. Any Help will be highly appreciated.

With Ali Zia's Answer:
I have this links already added:

```html
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/google-translate.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Latest Screenshot with Datatable plugin
[image]

Comment: apart from this, you can use datatables. :)

Comment: Thank you but I have bootstrap table already with mysql, how to implement then.

Comment: I checked it it looks beautiful and better than my one full page coding

Comment: But its not free

Comment: It is absolutely free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this style

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min‌​.css">
```

Use this js

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Give ID to your table `datatable`

Use this js in the footer

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').DataTable();
});
```

Make the HTML in following format

```
<table id="datatable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you let me try and then get back to you

Comment: If it does not work you can check the following link https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: At the bottom there is javascript, HTML and CSS. You can take help from there.

Comment: Yes remove all the code. Load all the data inside this table. This will automatically paginate it.

Comment: what about mysql query? where I use     $stmt_d=$mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, code FROM geo_countries LIMIT ?, ?");
       $stmt_d->bind_param('ii',$this_page_first_result,$results_per_page); limit option for paginator ?

Comment: remove that as well. Dont put limit in your mysql query either. Load all the data.

Comment: done now its looks less coding :) but there is no pagination button, very plain.

Comment: you can add styles as well. Let me tell you :) Have a look here https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html Please add the following js and css and it will look very pretty :D

Comment: I already used class="table table-striped table-bordered" bootstrap.min.css" & dataTables.bootstrap.min.css both are added already but still just showing numbers on pagination

Comment: That's the basic. If you want to modify it, you can modify it as per needs. If you are good with css then you can use it otherwise I can provide you the code for that as well :)

Comment: boostrap pagination codes by default doesn't required CSS but here, in this case, as its not loading, then a simple css code can help me.:)

Comment: Try putting https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css in your link tag as well below all css

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question with all links which are already added on the page. Still it doesn't works.

Comment: Can you give me a live link so that I can test it?

Comment: Also can you show me a screenshot of current pagination?

Comment: Hi live link is not available :( as its on localhost. But i am updating my question with the screenshot

Comment: Please have a look over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066237/datatable-styling-not-working

Comment: Also make sure to include all the links in header, and all the scripts in footer

Comment: It worked with this link  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"> You might want to update your answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: Thank you a lot, you save my life from future thousand lines of coding! :)

Comment: The pleasure is all mine. Happy coding bro.